# ViewFlipper not showing in custom DialogFragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android, viewflipper, android-dialogfragment

I created a custom DialogFragment that loads a custom layout called student_info_main_container.  This layout contains a ViewFlipper which I load with two additional layouts.  The problem is that the ViewFlipper doesn't show in my DialogFragment but the rest of the student_info_main_container layout does show.  Most of my work is done in OnCreateView.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class StudentInfoUIViewController : DialogFragment, IJoinClassView
    {
        private ViewFlipper studentInfoContentFlipper;

        public static StudentInfoUIViewController NewInstance() 
        {
            StudentInfoUIViewController frag = new StudentInfoUIViewController();     
            frag.SetStyle(DialogFragmentStyle.NoTitle, 0);

            return frag;
        }

        public override void OnAttach(Activity activity)
        {
            base.OnAttach(activity);
            Log.Debug("StudentInfoUIViewController", "OnAttach Called.");
        }

        //This is called to create the view and initialize the UI.  The UI isn't made visible until OnStart is called.
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            Dialog.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Top);

            //Inflate and set the main layout for this DialogFragment
            View mainView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.student_info_main_container, container, true);

            //Find the ViewFlipper in the mainView
            studentInfoContentFlipper = Activity.FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.studentInfoMainContainer_viewFlipper_studentInfoContent);

            //Inflate the layouts that are going to be added to the studentInfoContentFlipper ViewFlipper
            View joinSelectionView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.student_info_join_selection, null);
            View test = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.test, null);

            //Add the above views to the flipper.
            studentInfoContentFlipper.AddView(joinSelectionView, 0);
            studentInfoContentFlipper.AddView(test, 1);


            Log.Debug("StudentInfoUIViewController", "OnCreateView Called.");

            return mainView;
        }

        public override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            //UI is visible
            Log.Debug("StudentInfoUIViewController", "OnStart Called.");

        }               

    }
```

Comment: Can you share more details regarding the layout files did you use? Also, I don't use Mono for Android but you should use `inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.student_info_main_container, container, false);` and look for the `ViewFipper` in the inflated *mainView* layout.

Comment: Luksprog, that was the issue.  I was looking for the view flipper in the activity.  I'm still very very knew and all the major examples used Activity to look for the views.  Now that I know, it makes a lot more sense to look for the view of interest in it's container view.  Thank you so much.  Repost your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look for the `ViewFlipper` in the `Activity`, simply look for it in the inflated view(*mainView*) which will become the view for the `Fragment`. Also don't use the `Inflate()` method with the `boolean` parameter set to `true` as that will add the inflated view to the container which will be done again, automatically, by the system after `onCreateView` returns.